# Verify TLS encryped communication when querying LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, tls, starttls

I have a web application (not hosted on windows) that authenticates users by querying an LDAP server (a windows domain controller). The app is configured to use STARTTLS to encrypt communication with the LDAP server. I would like to verify that this is negotiated properly and that the connection is indeed encrypted with TLS.

What would be an effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just `tcpdump` a query from the application server and verify that the traffic exchanged is indeed encrypted.